# Teradata deletes multiline comments when creating/replacing procedure

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I`ll forgive to help with teradata 16.20 Maybe somebody faced such a problem

When i try to create/replace procedure in TD it works but every time i lost multiline commens.

**Example:**

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE test.RAS_TEST ()

BEGIN
DECLARE QQQQ INTEGER;
SET QQQQ = 0;

/*
DELETE FROM test.table
WHERE DAY_ID BETWEEN BEGIN_DATE AND END_DATE;
COMMIT;
*/

-- TEST

/*
TEST.WITH.STRING 
*/

END;
```

**And after:**

```
SHOW PROCEDURE test.RAS_TEST;
```

**Result:**

```
SHOW PROCEDURE test.RAS_TEST;

REPLACE PROCEDURE test.RAS_TEST ()

BEGIN
DECLARE QQQQ INTEGER;
SET QQQQ = 0;



-- TEST



END;
```

When another person who will do SHOW PROCEDURE will see the same BUT if another person copies the code and executes it, the result of SHOW will be complete, with all the lines, including multiline comments.

Comment: Are you using the ODBC driver to connect to the database? Use .NET Provider instead.

Comment: Yes, ODBC. Another persons using ODBC and it works :(